# Where em Laravel não retorna informações

Tags: laravel

No meu arquivo ProfissionalController.php, tenho o código:

```
public function vinculo($id)
{
    $profissional = Profissional::find($id);
    $unidades = Unidade::all();
    $vinculos = Vinculo::where('profissional_id', '=', $id);

    return view('profissionais.vinculo', compact('profissional', 'unidades', 'vinculos'));
}
```

Ele retorna os campos profissional e unidades. Porém os vínculos não são listados.

Meu arquivo vinculo.blade.php onde deveria aparecer os vínculos:

```
@foreach($vinculos as $vinculo)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$vinculo->vinculo}}</td>
        <td>{{$vinculo->cargo}}</td>
        <td>{{$vinculo->funcao}}</td>
        <td>{{$vinculo->horario}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{route('vinculos.edit', $vinculo->id)}}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
            <a href="{{route('vinculos.remove', $vinculo->id)}}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
            <a href="{{route('vinculos.show', $vinculo->id)}}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></i></a>
        </td>                                
    </tr>                         
@endforeach
```

Comment: [Leia a documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#collections). Lá explica que o `get` é usado para retornar os resultados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

faça isso:

```
$vinculos = Vinculo::where('profissional_id', '=', $id)->get();
```

O ->get() funciona para dizer que você terminou de construir sua query e quer "pegar"/executar para buscar os resultados.

Serve para fazer validações diferentes em alguns casos, ex:

```
$query = $items = Item::take(10)
   ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
   ->limit(10)
   ->with('categorias');

if ($user->isAdmin) {
    $query->where('type', '=', 'admin')
}

return $query->get();
```

No exemplo não importa a ordem que você define a query, a montagem dela só se dara quando o método get() é executado.

Espero que tenha ajudado.